# Shorter way to say "will be there"

Tags: synonyms

For an event, I would like to add next to the name of some participants, that they "will be there". For example,

1. Mr. AAA
2. Mr. BBB (will be there)
3. Ms. CCC

Can any one suggest a better, professional replacement for "will be there".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "participate" is a broadly used word when you want to say somebody will "join an event".

Comment: I want to say that this person "will be there" to encourage others to participate...

Comment: How's "will attend"?

Comment: thanks, Ricky and Jack. I will use it until I get a better one.

Comment: @Ricky Sorry my answer is the same as your comment - I just published it then saw yours

Comment: @Karson How about "assist (at)," i.e. be present as a helper or spectator? http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say they are an **attendee** or that they **will attend** the event or occasion.

> Attendee - One who is present at or attends a function

Comment: Or, for a single word, just ***attending,*** which I would have posted as an answer had it not been so similar to this one.

Comment: "attending" sounds better than "will attend". Thanks Andrew.

Answer (score 1):

You could just say

> Mr. AAA
>   Mr. BBB (confirmed).

Context would imply that confirmed refers to their attendance.

Comment: Thanks Peter, but for my purpose, I need to point out that the person will be there, without implying that the person has been invited and he/she had confirmed...

Comment: @Karson "Confirmed" is broadly used to mean the person will be there. If you want to mean that the person will be there without having been invited, it doesn't look professional at all.

Comment: @Karson: if the person hasn't told you that he/she will be there, how do you know? And if the person has told you that he/she will be there, there is nothing wrong with saying *(confirmed)*.