# What do you call people who have been invited to an event?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word to describe people who have been invited to an event (let's say a wedding or party).  When addressing the person, how should they be addressed?

> Dear, _________. We are excited to extend to you...

I have considered *Invited Guest*, but this suggests with the word "guest" that they will be attending.  Is the best term *Invitee*?  It sound's strange when used in a sentence.  Is there a better word to use?

**More information:**
To better explain... I have created a website where people can RSVP to my event.  Only people who have received an invitation should know about the website. I do not know the name of the visitor, but wish to address them in a short personal letter.

Comment: I am confused. The question suggests you are asking about the wording of the invitation. But in the title you say *who have been invited* suggesting that that stage is already past. In any event when writing to people it is not customary to begin with *Hello*. Normally one starts *Dear....*. It would also not be considered appropriate to address someone as *Guest* or *Invitee*. One usually uses the person's name e.g *Dear Hilda*, *Dear Charlie*, *Dear Mr and Mrs Fortescue, Dear Dr Howes* etc.

Comment: I have made an edit to try and explain my question better.  You are right about using "dear". @WS2

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284083/shorter-way-to-say-will-be-there/284085#284085

Comment: So am I to understand that this is a letter you intend to write before the wedding, but after you have received their acceptance? Why don't you just use their names? I'm still a bit puzzled when you say *before confronting them*. That suggests meeting them in person. If that is what you mean you certainly wouldn't start *Dear...* One would normally just call them by name.

Comment: Once an invited person recelves an invitation in the mail... they will be prompted to visit a website for details and to RSVP.  On the website  I want to write a short description and point of the event.  When I say confronting them, I meant addressing them.  Because I don't know everyone's IP addresses.. I won't be able to know the name  of the invited person when they visit the site. @WS2

Comment: Ah. It is becoming clearer. So this will be a letter on a website addressed to all the invitees in general. Is that right? In that case I see nothing wrong with saying *Dear Invited Guest*.

Comment: Correct.  Sorry for the confusion, I should have started with more details of my situation.

Comment: One might use "Dear friend of Banana Panorama" (or whatever "cause" the event is honoring or helping to support).

Comment: **Invitee** ought probably to be limited to discussions of the law of trespass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about ***Dear Friend***?

> friend
>
> : a person who gives assistance; patron; supporter. [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/friend)
>
> : (*used as a polite form of address or in ironic reference*) an acquaintance or a stranger one comes across. [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/friend)

Comment: Dear friend covers pretty much. +1)

Comment: I think this may be the best word for my situation.

Comment: I'm not certain "Dear friend" is either suitable, or very modern "natural" English ... it is the sort of intro you might see in a spam email from someone in Nigeria advising you you have inherited ten million dollars. On a website that the invitee has been interested enough to look up, I think you can just thank them for their interest, and go straight into the details. By the way, your "excitement" is not relevant to the reader, and I would avoid it.

Comment: I must confess, **Dear Friend** sounds a bit cheesy to me.

Answer (score 2):

*Invitee* or *attendee* would work, but these are very formal and impersonal. This is a case to use mail merge and personalize the message.

Comment: _Invitee_ is really best left as a  legal term.

Comment: Really? Maybe that's why I've never run into it. I don't read legal documents. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

How about
**Dear prospective guest**?